# Flutter build apk, throw SDK not found error

Tags: flutter

`Android` and `flutter` SDKs locations are placed in correct path into `local.properties` file:

```
sdk.dir=F:\\software\\sdk
flutter.sdk=F:\\software\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

when i try to run `build apk` command i get this error:

```
* Where:
Build file 'F:\software\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\screen-0.0.5\android\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'screen'.
> Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

`flutter doctor -v` command output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.153, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-10.0.pre.153 at F:\software\flutter
    • Framework revision 2e643651a9 (4 days ago), 2020-09-11 23:07:03 -0400
    • Engine revision 16b900b63e
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-117.0.dev)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at F:\software\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = F:\software\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • WAS LX1A (mobile) • 2XJDU17C14006203 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: did you add flutter to your path environment?

Comment: Maybe try giving us the output of `flutter doctor`

Comment: open `android` folder with android studio,try to clean and rebuild the project,after successful build close then run `flutter clean` then try to build app,make sure you setup is done correctly @DolDurma

Comment: @Uni yes, my post updated

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

i fixed `screen` library manually and after that building `apk` command worked fine